# Trouble using power mock with camel

Tags: apache-camel, powermock

Since I have to mock a static method, I am using **Power Mock** to test my application.
My application uses **Camel 2.1**2.
I define routes in *XML* that is read by *camel-spring* context.
There were no issues when `Junit` alone was used for testing.
While using power mock, I get the error listed at the end of the post.
I have also listed the XML used.
*Camel* is unable to recognize any of its tags when power mock is used.
I wonder whether the byte-level manipulation done by power mock to mock static methods interferes with camel engine in some way. Let me know what could possibly be wrong.

PS:

The problem disappears if I do not use power mock.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++   Error +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
[                          main] CamelNamespaceHandler          DEBUG Using      org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean as CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse JAXB   element; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element   (uri:"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring", local:"camelContext"). Expected elements are    <{}aggregate>,<{}aop>,<{}avro>,<{}base64>,<{}batchResequencerConfig>,<{}bean>,<{}beanPostProcessor>,<{}beanio>,<{}bindy>,<{}camelContext>,<{}castor>,<{}choice>,<{}constant>,<{}consumerTemplate>,<{}contextScan>,<{}convertBodyTo>,<{}crypto>,<{}csv>,<{}customDataFormat>,<{}customLoadBalancer>,<{}dataFormats>,<{}delay>,<{}description>,<{}doCatch>,<{}doFinally>,<{}doTry>,<{}dynamicRouter>,<{}el>,<{}endpoint>,<{}enrich>,<{}errorHandler>,<{}export>,<{}expression>,<{}expressionDefinition>,<{}failover>,<{}filter>,<{}flatpack>,<{}from>,<{}groovy>,<{}gzip>,<{}header>,<{}hl7>,<{}idempotentConsumer>,<{}inOnly>,<{}inOut>,<{}intercept>,<{}interceptFrom>,<{}interceptToEndpoint>,<{}javaScript>,<{}jaxb>,<{}jibx>,<{}jmxAgent>,<{}json>,<{}jxpath>,<{}keyStoreParameters>,<{}language>,<{}loadBalance>,<{}log>,<{}loop>,<{}marshal>,<{}method>,<{}multicast>,<{}mvel>,<{}ognl>,<{}onCompletion>,<{}onException>,<{}optimisticLockRetryPolicy>,<{}otherwise>,<{}packageScan>,<{}pgp>,<{}php>,<{}pipeline>,<{}policy>,<{}pollEnrich>,<{}process>,<{}properties>,<{}property>,<{}propertyPlaceholder>,<{}protobuf>,<{}proxy>,<{}python>,<{}random>,<{}recipientList>,<{}redeliveryPolicy>,<{}redeliveryPolicyProfile>,<{}ref>,<{}removeHeader>,<{}removeHeaders>,<{}removeProperty>,<{}resequence>,<{}rollback>,<{}roundRobin>,<{}route>,<{}routeBuilder>,<{}routeContext>,<{}routeContextRef>,<{}routes>,<{}routingSlip>,<{}rss>,<{}ruby>,<{}sample>,<{}secureRandomParameters>,<{}secureXML>,<{}serialization>,<{}setBody>,<{}setExchangePattern>,<{}setFaultBody>,<{}setHeader>,<{}setOutHeader>,<{}setProperty>,<{}simple>,<{}soapjaxb>,<{}sort>,<{}spel>,<{}split>,<{}sql>,<{}sslContextParameters>,<{}sticky>,<{}stop>,<{}streamCaching>,<{}streamResequencerConfig>,<{}string>,<{}syslog>,<{}template>,<{}threadPool>,<{}threadPoolProfile>,<{}threads>,<{}throttle>,<{}throwException>,<{}tidyMarkup>,<{}to>,<{}tokenize>,<{}topic>,<{}transacted>,<{}transform>,<{}unmarshal>,<{}validate>,<{}vtdxml>,<{}weighted>,<{}when>,<{}wireTap>,<{}xmlBeans>,<{}xmljson>,<{}xmlrpc>,<{}xpath>,<{}xquery>,<{}xstream>,<{}zip>,<{}zipFile>  at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler.parseUsingJaxb(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:169)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.springCamelContext(SpringCamelContext.java:100)
    at com.ericsson.bss.edm.integrationFramework.Context.<init>(Context.java:50)
    at com.ericsson.bss.edm.integrationFramework.RouteEngine.main(RouteEngine.java:55)
    at com.ericsson.bss.edm.integrationFramework.RouteEngineTest.testMultiRouteCondition(RouteEngineTest.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:312)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:112)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:73)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring", local:"camelContext"). Expected elements are <{}aggregate>,<{}aop>,<{}avro>,<{}base64>,<{}batchResequencerConfig>,<{}bean>,<{}beanPostProcessor>,<{}beanio>,<{}bindy>,<{}camelContext>,<{}castor>,<{}choice>,<{}constant>,<{}consumerTemplate>,<{}contextScan>,<{}convertBodyTo>,<{}crypto>,<{}csv>,<{}customDataFormat>,<{}customLoadBalancer>,<{}dataFormats>,<{}delay>,<{}description>,<{}doCatch>,<{}doFinally>,<{}doTry>,<{}dynamicRouter>,<{}el>,<{}endpoint>,<{}enrich>,<{}errorHandler>,<{}export>,<{}expression>,<{}expressionDefinition>,<{}failover>,<{}filter>,<{}flatpack>,<{}from>,<{}groovy>,<{}gzip>,<{}header>,<{}hl7>,<{}idempotentConsumer>,<{}inOnly>,<{}inOut>,<{}intercept>,<{}interceptFrom>,<{}interceptToEndpoint>,<{}javaScript>,<{}jaxb>,<{}jibx>,<{}jmxAgent>,<{}json>,<{}jxpath>,<{}keyStoreParameters>,<{}language>,<{}loadBalance>,<{}log>,<{}loop>,<{}marshal>,<{}method>,<{}multicast>,<{}mvel>,<{}ognl>,<{}onCompletion>,<{}onException>,<{}optimisticLockRetryPolicy>,<{}otherwise>,<{}packageScan>,<{}pgp>,<{}php>,<{}pipeline>,<{}policy>,<{}pollEnrich>,<{}process>,<{}properties>,<{}property>,<{}propertyPlaceholder>,<{}protobuf>,<{}proxy>,<{}python>,<{}random>,<{}recipientList>,<{}redeliveryPolicy>,<{}redeliveryPolicyProfile>,<{}ref>,<{}removeHeader>,<{}removeHeaders>,<{}removeProperty>,<{}resequence>,<{}rollback>,<{}roundRobin>,<{}route>,<{}routeBuilder>,<{}routeContext>,<{}routeContextRef>,<{}routes>,<{}routingSlip>,<{}rss>,<{}ruby>,<{}sample>,<{}secureRandomParameters>,<{}secureXML>,<{}serialization>,<{}setBody>,<{}setExchangePattern>,<{}setFaultBody>,<{}setHeader>,<{}setOutHeader>,<{}setProperty>,<{}simple>,<{}soapjaxb>,<{}sort>,<{}spel>,<{}split>,<{}sql>,<{}sslContextParameters>,<{}sticky>,<{}stop>,<{}streamCaching>,<{}streamResequencerConfig>,<{}string>,<{}syslog>,<{}template>,<{}threadPool>,<{}threadPoolProfile>,<{}threads>,<{}throttle>,<{}throwException>,<{}tidyMarkup>,<{}to>,<{}tokenize>,<{}topic>,<{}transacted>,<{}transform>,<{}unmarshal>,<{}validate>,<{}vtdxml>,<{}weighted>,<{}when>,<{}wireTap>,<{}xmlBeans>,<{}xmljson>,<{}xmlrpc>,<{}xpath>,<{}xquery>,<{}xstream>,<{}zip>,<{}zipFile>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:647)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:120)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1052)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:464)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:75)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:152)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:127)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.BinderImpl.associativeUnmarshal(BinderImpl.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.BinderImpl.unmarshal(BinderImpl.java:132)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler.parseUsingJaxb(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:167)
    ... 72 more
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

++++++++++++++++++++++++  Route.xml    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <route id="simpleroute">
            <from uri="ftp://admin@x.y.z.a:2121/?password=admin&amp;noop=true&amp;maximumReconnectAttempts=3&amp;download=false&amp;delay=2000&amp;throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true;"/> 
            <to uri="file:/home/emeensa/NetBeansProjects/CamelFileCopier/output" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Answer (score 1):

When you have these JAXB binding errors with spring then in the past it has been troubles with JAXB version. Can you check the classpath if you have JAXB 2.1 or 2.2. Sometimes the JAXB that comes witht the JDK is too old and buggy, and you may need to have JAXB added to your classpath.

Another idea could be that the error says it does not understand the local namespace. You can try using a prefix, eg such as camel in the XML top, and use

```
<camel:camelContext>
```

instead.

Comment: The project is maven driven.I do not explicitly specify JAXB as dependencies in my pom.They are downloaded as dependencies from camel-core or camel-spring pom.The JAXB versions downloaded as dependencies are  jaxb-api-2.1.jar  
jaxb-impl-2.2.6.jar  
Since I do not explicitly specify these as dependencies in my pom, they are downloaded as dependencies from camel-core or camel-spring pom.Should these be updated?  
I have tried using <camel:camelContext> prefix, but the problem persists.Everything works fine when PowerMock is not used.
I suspect the custom class-loaders used by PowerMock.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work as follows :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.xml.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.springframework.*","org.apache.commons.logging.*","org.w3c.*","javax.management.*"})
```

The list of packages in the `@PowerMockIgnore` annotation was found by trial and error and I have pretty much no idea what I have done, but my unit test now runs and produces the same results as when I didn't use the `@RunWith` annotation.

Comment: Not exactly the same.. but in a similar context, this helped! So, thanks. :)